# When changing ip settings from different network to migrate data in Apache IoTDB, why did the query statement reported error?

Tags: ip-address, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to migrate data stored in Apache IoTDB, and during this progress I need to change my IP address settings. I changed the old ip `172.16.60.11` to the new one `192.16.60.11`, which are referred to the same server but different network (internal and external), and then restarted the system. Then, the SQL query statement reports an error stating the ip setting is still the previous ip address. My case is that if I change the IP back, I will not be able to connect to the host. Do I need to modify the ip elsewhere? Or anyone know if I just want to migrate data, what should I do to achieve in this case?

Comment: Please remember, SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

Don’t delete your original cluster data. Simply compress the data directory of Apache IoTDB and put it on a new server (with the new ip address) to decompress it, and then execute the `ts import` command to import data. Remember to execute `flush` and `merge` first to avoid losing data. You can also consider upgrading to version 1.3.0 before proceeding.